# How do I fix a CORS error that I'm getting when trying to make a multiplayer snake game

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

can somebody help me fix this error: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5500/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OAQWdpu' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:5500' that is not equal to the supplied origin."

I have been following this video on how to make a snake game:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppcBIHv_ZPs&t=2s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia", got to around 15:00, then can't proceed because of the error

I tried copying some of the code from the socket.io website on how to fix CORS, but it does not work

https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/

was running index.html from the live server extension for vscode on microsoft edge

server.js:

```
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:5500",
        allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
        credentials: true
    }
});

io.on('connection', client =>{
client.emit('init', { data: 'hello world' });
});

io.listen(5500);
```

index.js:

```
const BG_COLOUR = '#231f20';
const SNAKE_COLOUR = '#c2c2c2';
const FOOD_COLOUR = '#e66916';

// client-side
const socket = io('http://localhost:5500', {
  withCredentials: true,
  extraHeaders: {
    "my-custom-header": "abcd"
  }
}); 
socket.on('init', handleInit);

const gameScreen = document.getElementById('gameScreen');

let canvas, ctx;

const gameState = {
    player: {
        pos: {
            x: 3,
            y: 10,
        },
        vel: {
            x: 1,
            y: 0,
        },
        snake: [
            {x: 1, y: 10},
            {x: 2, y: 10},
            {x: 3, y: 10},
        ],
    },
    food: {
        x: 7,
        y: 7,
    },
    gridsize: 20,
};

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;

    ctx.fillStyle = BG_COLOUR;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', keydown);

}
function keydown(e){
    console.log(e.KeyCode);
}

init();

function paintGame(state){
    ctx.fillStyle = BG_COLOUR;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const food = state.food;
    const gridsize = state.gridsize;
    const size = canvas.width / gridsize;
    ctx.fillStyle = FOOD_COLOUR;
    ctx.fillRect(food.x * size, food.y * size, size, size);

    paintPlayer(state.player, size, SNAKE_COLOUR);
}

function paintPlayer(playerState, size, colour){
    const snake = playerState.snake;

    ctx.fillStyle = colour;
    for(let cell of snake){
        ctx.fillRect(cell.x * size, cell.y * size, size , size);
    }
}

paintGame(gameState);

function handleInit(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MultiPlayer Snake</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  <section class="vh-100">
    <div class="container h-100">

     
      <div id="gameScreen" class="h-100">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">

          <!-- <h1>Your game code is: <span id="gameCodeDisplay"></span></h1> -->

          <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.1/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need inform also common headers used by application, such as post, get. At allowedHeaders in server side

Comment: where do I find that?

Comment: Access-Control-Allowed-Origin should contain the Origin of the request, not the host of the server handling the request - i.e. in this case it should be `http://127.0.0.1:5500` since that's what is making the request

Comment: Into cors configuration at almost top server script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed server code to

```
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
        allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
        credentials: true
    }
});

io.on('connection', client =>{
    client.emit('init', { data: 'hello world' });
});

io.listen(5500);
```